# Importing pandas in cx_freeze frozen Python Application very slow

Tags: python, pandas, cx-freeze

In my cx_freeze frozen python application it takes 8.5 seconds to import pandas.

- python 2.7 32bit and python 3.3 64bit
- pandas 0.12.0

myprogram.py

```
while 1:
    input = raw_input(">>")
    if input == "quit()": break
    try:
        t = time.clock()
        exec(input, globals(), locals())
        print ("%f" % (time.clock() - t))
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))
```

setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {
"includes": ['pandas'],
"packages": [],
'excludes' : ['PyQt4.uic.port_v3', 'Tkconstants', 'tcl', 'tk', 'doctest', '_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger', 'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'Tkinter', 'tables', 'zmq', 'win32', 'Pythonwin', 'Cython', 'statmodels', 'cvxopt', '_sqlite3', '_ssl', '_testcapi', 'markupsafe', 'numexpr', '_elementtree', '_hashlib', '_testcapi', 'bz2', 'simplejson', 'pyexpat', 'lxml', 'matplotlib', 'guidata', 'PyQt4', 'PySide', 'scipy', '_multiprocessing', '_ctypes', 'PIL'],

"include_files": []}

setup(
name = "my_program",
version="2.0.0",
description="",
author = "",
options = { "build_exe": build_exe_options},
executables = [Executable("my_program.py", shortcutName="my_program", shortcutDir="DesktopFolder")])
```

In my_program.exe

```
>>import pandas
8.579099
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong, but is it any better if you move pandas from `includes` to `packages` in setup.py?

Comment: No, moving pandas to "packages" gives the same result

Comment: Weird, I don't know what could be causing that. If you want to debug it, I'd put calls to print the time in amongst pandas imports, to work out which module is taking a long time.

Comment: In pandas 0.13.0 loads in 0.38s with python 3.3 64bit